# How to have the same gradual speed increment with objects coming from a pool?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a game with LibGDX were asteroids are spawn from the top edge of the screen at a random x position, the asteroids move down with a gradual speed increment of 0.1f, when the asteroid leaves the bottom edge of screen it is sent to a pool to be reused. The problem i have is that after some time the asteroids coming from the pool have different speeds. I want all the asteroids to move at the same gradual speed.

here is the update and reset method in my Asteroid class:

```
public void update(float delta){
    y -= speed * delta;
    speed += 0.1f;
}

@Override
public void reset() {
    // place asteroid at random x position
    x = MathUtils.random(minSpawnPoint, maxSpawnPoint);

    // place asteroid above screen edge
    y = Constants.CAMERA_HEIGHT + Constants.ASTEROID_MAX_SIZE;

}
```

Comment: you gotta reset the speed somewhere like you do the x and y positions. Put speed = initial somewhere in the reset method. I don't know if it's intentional but you're adding to the speed every update tick so your asteroids have some acceleration.

Comment: The asteroids are supposed to be accelerating at the same rate. the problem i have is that they have different acceleration rates.

Comment: well the asteroids you reuse from the pool are going to have higher initial speeds because I don't see you resetting the speed anywhere.

Comment: I don't want to reset to the initial speed, i want the asteroid to be re-spawn and have the current speed.
for example like the acceleration in the game [Canabalt](http://adamatomic.com/canabalt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you want all of the asteroids to start out slow and increase speed at the same time so that the asteroids always have the same speed relative to each other.

If this is the case, then you need to have only one global speed variable (outside of your asteroid class) that each asteroid will use to update its position. Each asteroid cannot maintain its own local speed variable because the longer a particular asteroid is on the screen the higher its speed will be. This will cause the asteroids to have different speeds depending on how long they have been on the screen.

To fix this, move your speed variable to the class that holds your asteroid pool. Then calculate the change in y (deltaY) by multiplying the speed by delta time and pass this value value into all of your asteroids.

So now, instead of having each asteroid take delta time in the update method they will take the change in y position and you can use this value to update the asteroid's position accordingly.

```
public void update(float deltaY){
    y -= deltaY;
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i want to achieve, but should i calculate the change in y from the asteroids pool class? and when you say "pass this value into all of your asteroids" do you mean passing the value in the Asteroids class?

Comment: In your render method you can do a for each - asteroid.setSpeed(speed)

Comment: Thanks guys it worked out now i moved the speed variable to the game screen and updated it in the render method.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure your classes were setup, but I was thinking along the lines of an AsteroidManager class that holds the pool of asteroids & adds/removes them from the screen as needed. This would be a good place to set the speed for the asteroids so that all of your asteroid data is together. The AsteroidManager class would also have an update method and within that it would update the speed, calculate deltaY, and then pass that into all of the asteroid classes to update their positions. Also, I should have used updatePosition(float deltaY) so that it's clear this is updating the position.